# How to solve "TypeError: $(...).length is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").length();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

Or see demo and full code here : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/6FzSb/4177/

I use jquery 3.0.1

When executed, there exist error :

TypeError: $(...).length is not a function

How can I solve it?

Comment: `length` is a value not a function use it like this: `$(...).length`!

Comment: Just Google your own question title.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Instead of this

```
$("#myList li").length();
```

Use this:

```
$("#myList li").length;
```

The `$("#myList li")` returns an array like object. All array like objects have a property called `length`, which when be read returns the number of items contained in the array like object. That being said there isn't any function called length. Hence `length()` is meaningless.

Comment: `$(...)` returns an array-like object not an array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir correct...my bad...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir aren't arrays object in javascript?

Comment: @JustARandomProgrammer Of course arrays are objects, but there is a big difference between an array-like object and an array object. For instance, on an array object you can call methods like `map`, `filter` etc...because this methods are declared on the `Array.prototype`, where `Array` is the constructor of all arrays. When you write `var array = [];` is equivalent as `var array = new Array()` . On the other hand array like objects aren't created based on the `Array`, but they have a property called `length`, which has the same meaning like the same property of array objects.

Comment: @JustARandomProgrammer Pretty much everything in JS is an object, but that doesn't mean we can't use words like **arrays**, **functions** ... Here I emphasized that the return value of `$(...)` is an object object and not an array object that you could use array functions on it such as `forEach`, `concat`, `push` ...

Comment: It's working for me...upvote from my side

Answer (score 4):

`length` is a property, not a function, so remove the `()`

```
$("#myList li").length;
```

Comment: _is a property_??? Functions could be properties too!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir "*The array length* ***property*** ", Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: I didn't say `length` is not a property. I said `length` is a property and object could have functions as property which make the sentence: _`length` is a property, not a function_ meaningless!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, okay, I see your point now... but in my defense a *function* always has `()` where a *property* doesn't... or am I mistaking?

Comment: If the function is a property of an object, then it can be called with parentheses and it is a property at the same time. You can say that "`children` is a function property of the jQuery object." `children` is both a function and a property (aka *method*).

Comment: Property of an object mean a key-value pair of that object where the key is a string and the value could be anything (numbers, strings, function, null, undefined, other objects ...)!

Comment: Read the first paragraph [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). It sais _**A property's value can be a function, in which case the property is known as a method.**_!

Answer (score 2):

`length` is not a function it is just `Yourthings.length` without ().
more doc at [length documentation](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle it says it is not a function because it really isn't. Length in javascript arrays is property so you should call it like

```
array.length
```

since dom selector returns array of dom elements you should also use length without parenthesis